# After editing text using vue.js how to submit and modify the text in a database?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

- I have some text strings stored in a table in the column "answer.name"
- These text strings represent answers to a question in a tool I've developed. You can see the the "Add an answer" section in the picture below:

[image]

- This section is made using vue.js
- I need to edit answers text (in this picture "No, mai", "Sì, sempre", "Sì, se invia un fax"
- Here is what I did:

  input v-model="answer.name" placeholder="modify me"

{{ answer.name }}

- Here the result:

[image]

- Now is possible for me to edit the text

Question is: how can I submit in some way after modifying text and change the text in the db table?

I've added this line:

button onclick="setNewValue()">Modify Answer</button

- Here the result:

[image]

It should call a function:

```
function setNewValue() {
    document.getElementById('answer.name').value = 'New value';
}
```

But at now I'm not able to go on

Comment: binding the element to a variable is a start - but you'll need some sort of AJAX request I should think - a POST request probably - to your server - where it takes the request and applies it as appropriate to the database

Comment: without knowing your backend technology this is hard to answer. Assuming you have a REST-Backend-Server, you can probably create a `saveModifiedAnswers` method that you can call using a AJAX request...

Comment: Sounds like you only have a frontend up to now. You need a server application that receives (and usually also provides) data and takes care of saving and further processing.

Comment: I've updated my question adding progresses